B&D CM2043 Rechargeable Lawn Mower Issue
Newbie here, so I apologize in advance for my stupidity.
We have a Black & Decker CM2043 40V rechargeable cordless electric lawn mower that will not stay running if the blade is attached.
It will run fine if I remove the blade.
What am I missing?

How old is the battery?  Turning/spinning the blade takes more power, than maybe what the battery can put out.  Battery is almost dead.

The batteries are original. I tested them with a basic multimeter and they are still showing around 39V.

Disconnect the battery and spin the blade.  A wood stick is safer than fingers.  Blade might be binding.  Also check all electrical connections for tightness/pushed fully in.  Had a push-in connector that was attached/still locked together.  It was loose about 1/16 inch preventing contact.

The blade spins freely and will spin for a few seconds before the mowers dies.
I just tried connecting a different style Ryobi battery using jumper cables and I guess I couldn’t get a good enough connection because it wouldn’t start at all.

Also, if the batteries were weak, wouldn’t they eventually die?
With the blade removed the mower will run for a long time on the same battery.

You didn’t say how old (or what chemistry: nicad or lithium) the batteries were. 39v with no load is potentially meaningless.

Okay, answered part of my question: batteries are lithium, but still need to know age of battery. They don’t last forever.

Batteries are lithium. 2 AH.
They are original to the mower.
They do not die quickly when operating the lawn mower with the blade removed.

How old is the mower?

A couple years. Not sure.

I wish I could help. Signs point to failed batteries, but not conclusive. If you bought new batteries that were returnable, you’d know for sure. (B+D isn’t total junk, but it’s not like they’re using premium batteries or anything.)
